# Behavior of numpy atleast_3d()

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain the behavior of np.atleast_3d() to me?

From using np.atleast_2d() I thought is was similar to adding np.newaxis while putting whatever it is passed to it the last dimension:

```
np.atleast_2d(3.0)
>>> array([[ 3.]])

np.atleast_2d([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
>>> array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]])
```

But np.atleast_3d() seems to behave quite different

```
np.atleast_3d([[2.9, 3.0]])
>>> array([[[ 2.9],
            [ 3. ]]])
```

The documentation states

```
For example, a 1-D array of shape (N,) becomes a view of shape (1, N, 1),
and a 2-D array of shape (M, N) becomes a view of shape (M, N, 1).
```

I would have expected (M, N) to become (1, M, N) and (N,) to become (1, 1, N, 1)

Isn't this behavior misleading?

Comment: You can see the actual code with `np.source(np.atleast_3d)`.  It does different things depending on the number of dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from `atleast_2d`:

```
    if len(ary.shape) == 0:
        result = ary.reshape(1, 1)
    elif len(ary.shape) == 1:
        result = ary[newaxis,:]
    else:
        result = ary
```

So it uses the `newaxis` trick if the array is 1d.

For 3d:

```
    if len(ary.shape) == 0:
        result = ary.reshape(1, 1, 1)
    elif len(ary.shape) == 1:
        result = ary[newaxis,:, newaxis]
    elif len(ary.shape) == 2:
        result = ary[:,:, newaxis]
    else:
        result = ary
```

It too uses the `newaxis` trick, but in different way for 1 and 2d arrays.  It does what the docs say.

There are other ways of changing the shape.  For example, `column_stack` uses

```
array(arr, copy=False, subok=True, ndmin=2).T
```

`expand_dims` uses

```
a.reshape(shape[:axis] + (1,) + shape[axis:])
```

Comment: @Joe consider up voting if you like the answer enough to accept it!